# Can I capture invited users?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an app, and part of the function is to ask users to invite their friends. Once 10 of their friends join the app, then the original user gets a reward. Is this possible to do with the facebook API? Here is my current code for inviting users.

```
   <script>
   FB.init({
   appId:'APP_ID',
   cookie:true,
   status:true,
   xfbml:true
   });

   function FacebookInviteFriends()
  {
  FB.ui({
  method: 'apprequests', 
  message: 'Your Message diaolog'
  });
  }
  </script>


  //HTML Code
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <a href='#' onclick="FacebookInviteFriends();"> 
   Facebook Invite Friends Link
   </a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have an app, and part of the function is to ask users to invite their friends. Once 10 of their friends join the app, then the original user gets a reward. Is this possible to do with the facebook API?

You can use the `data` parameter while sending a request to put in any kind of identifier you like – could be for example the sender’s user id.

Then, once an invited user acts upon a request they received, you read the request object’s details from the API, you’ll get that `data` value back.

Comment: Thanks for that, do you have an example ?

Comment: See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/, “Properties”